# Problems with loading native library/missing methods: no ttJdbcCS in java.library.path

Tags: macos, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, timesten

Iam facing one problem while connecting the timesten client to the server The SQL Exception which Iam getting is pasted below:-

Problems with loading native library/missing methods: no ttJdbcCS in java.library.path

I am working with MAC OS X 10.7.2 and my timesten client version is 11.2.1.0

I have also changed the Java Preferences from 64-bit to 32-bit but still whenever i tried to connect with the SQL Developer it gives me the above error.

Please help me as it is required for my graduation project!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the by doing the following:-

The key things you need to be sure to do (in a terminal window) are:

1. Be sure to . in the TimesTen environment script /bin/ttenv.sh to set the full TT environment.
2. Change directory to SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper
3. Run 'sh sqldeveloper.sh -J-d32'

and all should be fine.

Thanks all for their help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know OS X. On linux I use next

- > export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/TimesTen/timesten/lib/

(directory where ttJdbcCS.so located)

- Java must be same "bithes" (32 or 64) as TimesTen installation